# Swift - Can't access struct properties

Tags: swift, structure

Learning swift but a little confused as to the below. I have struct created and instantiated, but I cannot access the property of the struct inside of my view controller class unless the struct is inside one my my class methods. See below, why would this be the case?

```
class WeatherViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, WeatherManagerDelegate {



    //create new weather manager struct
    var weatherManager = WeatherManager()

    //can't access property here, but I can access it inside of functions within this
    //class, see below under viewDidLoad()
     weatherManager.delegate = self

    @IBOutlet weak var conditionImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //can access property here
        weatherManager.delegate = self

    }
```

Comment: I assume "the struct" refers to the `WeatherManager` object (based on comments in the code)? You might want to edit the question text to say that explicitly.

Comment: When you say "can't access property here" in `viewDidLoad`, did you mean *can* access property?

Comment: Note that it's very strange for `WeatherManager` to be a struct and also have a delegate. Having a delegate suggests that there is some identity to the object. For example, if you passed it to a function, you'd expect the function to have the same object as the caller. That's not how structs work. They're values. So if you pass `weatherManager` to a function, there will be two independent WeatherManager, each with its own delegate. I doubt you mean this. You probably meant WeatherManager to be a class. (This has nothing to do with your question, however. cschatz has the answer there.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't where the `WeatherManager` object is declared and created. The problem is that this line:

```swift
weatherManager.delegate = self
```

is a **command** (technically a **statement**), not a declaration. (The line above it **is** a declaration, one that happens to also set the `weatherManager` property's default value). This is a pretty universal rule in most languages in the C++/Java family -- see short C++ example below. A command (statement) must be inside some method (or function, in non-OOP programming), not at the top level of a file or class. In Swift, actions like setting an object's delegate would typically go in the view controller's `viewDidLoad`.

---

```
int x = 0;  // legal: declaring a global variable                               

x = x + 42; // NOT legal: this is a statement, not a declaraiton                

int main()
{
  x = x + 42; // legal: now we're inside a function                             
  return 0;
}
```